# Django - Use forloop.counter0

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I would like show element in my list on template html like that :

```
<table class="table table-striped col-md-12">
    <tbody>
        {% for row in list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ ..... }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

When the `len(list)` evolve, I need to call new row manually.
So to have a generic call and dependent of the length on my list I choice the method `forloop.counter0`, but when I write my code, I have error or no elements on my screen.

```
<tr>
  {% for i in "xxx" %}
      <td>{{ row.forloop.counter0 }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Comment: What is `list`? it sounds more as though you need an object model instead of random indexing

Comment: because on my view i read csv and get element on list:         list_test = []
        for row in reader:
            list_test.append((row))

Comment: Does the `row` variable have a `forloop` member? Also, I'm really unsure of what you're trying to do. There's one  `{% endfor %}` extra...

Comment: just i would like switch element on the loop for (first div) by the second div, and do this : {for } div2 {end for}

Comment: i will show all element on my list, this list are not static, on this list you can have 1 row or a lot of row, i would like show this row with forloop to add new row, not write row.0,row.1,... manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to look up the index at all, just have another forloop inside that loops over the row

```
{% for i in row %}
   <td>{{ i }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

If you need anything more granular, you might want to look into making an actual model to represent the data, and then iterate over a list of this model.